# how to read nth number of row in csv magento

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, importexport

yesterday i was working read data from csv in magento. I know that i can read date from csv in magento using this function.

```
Varien_File_Csv()
```

but what i want to know is how to read a fix number of row? i want to read it in multiple partbecause file have more than 100k rows. everytime i have to search a data in all rows. so i thought instead of read all data at once i should do it in part. i.e what everdata i am searching if its available in first 1k row so why i read it next. so can some 1 tell me how to read data from 1-1000 rows or 1001-2000 row ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am your position then I will upload This csv to my table and perform my task on `dbtable`

For uploading csv to db you can use below query

```
<?php
 $query = <<<eof
 LOAD DATA INFILE '$fileName'
 INTO TABLE tableName
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1,field2,field3,etc)
eof;

$db->query($query);
?>
```